# Servlet Spec 3.0 not rendering JSP include

Tags: java, spring, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have tried using both Tomcat 7 and Tomcat 8 RC 5 but my JSP include is not rendering.

I am using Spring MVC (don't think this matters though).

My JSP looks like this:

```
<jsp:include page="includes/header.jsp" />
It Worked!
<jsp:include page="includes/footer.jsp" />
```

When the page gets rendered it looks like this

```
<jsp:include page="includes/header.jsp" />
It Worked!
<jsp:include page="includes/footer.jsp" />
```

In my Pom file I am including:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

My web.xml file looks like this:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     id="Blog" version="3.0">
<display-name>Blog</display-name>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/error/404.html</location>
</error-page>
```

My App Initializer looks like this:

```
public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new     AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    context.setConfigLocation("com.package.to.AppConfig");
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("DispatcherServlet", new DispatcherServlet(context));
    servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    servlet.addMapping("/*");
}
```

What am I doing wrong?  Why is my include not being rendered correctly?

I have also tried the following with the same result:

```
<%@ include file="includes/header.jsp" %>
It Worked!
<%@ include file="includes/footer.jsp" %>
```

Controller Method:

```
@Controller
public class PageController {

@Autowired
PageService pageService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/*", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index(HttpServletRequest request){
    String path = request.getRequestURI().substring(request.getContextPath().length());
    Page page = pageService.getPageByUrl(path);
    if(page == null){
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException();
    }

    return page.getTemplate().getPageTemplatePath();
}
```

}

AppConfig

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"package.to.scan"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableWebMvc
@PropertySource("/${env:prod}.properties")
@Import({DataSourceConfig.class})
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
Environment environment;

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver(){
    InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    internalResourceViewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
    internalResourceViewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return internalResourceViewResolver;
}

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/styles/**").addResourceLocations("/styles/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("/images/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/scripts/**").addResourceLocations("/scripts/");
}

}
```

Comment: Can you show the controller method that forwards to your jsp? And I'd like to see your relevant context configuration.

Comment: Added Controller Method.

Comment: And your context has an `InternalResourceViewResolver` or something else?

Comment: It does I posted this as well now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a quick fix, change your `DispatcherServlet` mapping to `/` instead of `/*`.

You have a `/*` mapping for your `DispatcherServlet`. In other words, any un-named  `RequestDispatcher` `forward`s or `include`s will go through this same `Servlet`.

So when your `InternalResourceViewResolver`'s resolved view tries to forward to, for example,

```
/WEB-INF/jsp/somepage.jsp
```

the `DispatcherServlet` will be chosen to process it. Since you don't have a `@Controller` method that handles requests to that URL, the `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` registered by

```
@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}
```

will be used. The `DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer` registers a `DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler` which dispatches the request to the `default` `Servlet`. It does this by acquiring the `default` `Servlet` by name

```
@Override
public void handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    RequestDispatcher rd = this.servletContext.getNamedDispatcher(this.defaultServletName);
    if (rd == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("A RequestDispatcher could not be located for the default servlet '" +
                this.defaultServletName +"'");
    }
    rd.forward(request, response);
}
```

With Tomcat, this is typically [`org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/servlets/DefaultServlet.html) which is

> The default resource-serving servlet for most web applications, used
>   to serve static resources such as HTML pages and images.

In other words, it does not process jsps, it just feeds them directly to the `HttpServletResponse` `OutputStream`.

**If instead, you change your `DispatcherServlet` url-mapping to `/`**, the `Servlet` container will again go through the rules for matching urls. These are described in the [Servlet Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/). The third one goes

> If the last segment in the URL path contains an extension (e.g. .jsp),
>   the servlet  container will try to match a servlet that handles
>   requests for the extension. An  extension is defined as the part of
>   the last segment after the last ’.’ character

In this case, Tomcat, by default, will find `org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet` which is mapped to

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jspx</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This url-mapping matches `/WEB-INF/jsp/somepage.jsp` and is therefore chosen. The `JspServlet` does render jsps and so that will do the trick.

---

Somewhat related note, the `servlet-api` should be provided by the `Servlet` container, not your web application.

Change this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

to this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Regardless if this is the cause or not, you should make this change.

Comment: @user1304051 Please see the full answer.